# Android:AsyncTask - how to get results?

Tags: android, jsoup

I want:
Parse url with Jsoup lib, get some data from url, and after work with them in another method.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(pdialog.isShowing())
        pdialog.cancel();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();

    pdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pdialog.setCancelable(false);
    pdialog.setMessage("Loading");
    pdialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.interdag.ru/afisha").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

how i can to get Jsoup.connect().get() result?

---

This code return errors:

```
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462): Activity com.example.afisha.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40fc2db8 that was originally added here
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.afisha.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40fc2db8 that was originally added here
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at com.example.afisha.GetData.onPreExecute(GetData.java:46)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at com.example.afisha.GetData.getData(GetData.java:65)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at com.example.afisha.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-29 06:34:45.214: E/WindowManager(1462):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is "doc" variable. i think in that u will get the result.

Comment: @СулейманДибиров is asynctask an inner class of activity or is it in a different `.java `file?

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.interdag.ru/afisha").get();
```

replace with

```
return Jsoup.connect("http://www.interdag.ru/afisha").get();
```

the object returned in post execute is the result u can use it.

Comment: which is the context ur passing to progress dialog

Comment: u should pass activity context over here. please if ur issue got solved accept the ans and upvote it